# slicing flag with parfor in MatLab, cannot identify error

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

MatLab flagged an error in my `parfor` loop. The error is roughly 'valid indices are restricted in parfor loops'.  Have read the [sliced variables documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/sliced-variable.html) and cannot determine the problem. Similar code and my attempted diagnosis follow.

```
N=10;
M=20;

DTc = zeros(M,2,2);
DTcs1 = zeros(M,N);
DTcs2 = zeros(M,N);

parfor kIter = 1:M
     DT = eye(2);
     DTs = reshape(repmat(eye(2),[N,1]),[N,2,2]);
     DTc(kIter,:,:) = DT; %flagged
     DTcs1(kIter,:) = DTs(:,1,1); %flagged
     DTcs2(kIter,:) = DTs(:,2,2); %flagged
end
```

I read the documentation and `DTc`, `DTcs1` and `DTcs2` seem to fit the four characteristics of sliced variables.

Update, the flags went away after I retyped the code. Not exactly sure what happened. Would like to avoid this error. Does anyone know what happened?

Comment: Can you kindly provide a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated the example. 'DTc' is now also flagged and I cannot determine why.

Comment: Weird. Does `DTc(kIter,1:2,1:2) = DT(1:2,1:2);` also get flagged?

Comment: Yes. `DTcs1(kIter,1:M) = DTs(1:M,1,1);` was also flagged.

Comment: Update. Follow advice from [another thread](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/123922-sliced-variables-in-parfor-loop-restricted-indexing). Tried `DTc=cell(N,1)` and `DTc{kIter}=DT`. No luck.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem in Matlab 2019b. No clue what's  actually happening. Maybe save such an example, restart matlab and only open that file. Does the error persist?

Comment: Are You sure, that Your variables are not global?

Comment: @Daniel, retyping seemed to resolve the error. No clue what happened.

Comment: @zlon, the variables are not global.

Comment: In my case everything ok. Try to add clear all